# number of bytes actually written to device in QSerialPort

Tags: c++, linux, qt, serial-port

In QSerialPort there is a bytesWritten signal ( inherited from QIODevice ) which is emitted when a number of bytes are written to the underying device.
If we send 10Kb of data with the QSerialPort write method, the bytesWritten signal will be emitted immediately indicating 4k of data has been written into the buffer of the Linux serial port device ( since the default serial port write buffer size is 1page=4096B).

However for displaying a progress bar we need to know how much data has been transmitted by the serial port.
Is there any such functionality in QSerialPort or even the Linux serial port character device?!

Note: 
There is waitForBytesWritten in QSerialPort which waits for the buffer to be emptied, but this method blocks the event loop and freezes the UI. Moving the serial port into another thread may seem like a good solution but in my case a lot of changes would be needed and this is not preferred.

Edit:
There is ioctl for getting the number of bytes in the output buffer, called TIOCOUTQ. I can't verify that this applicable to the serial port or not, however I tested it and I am getting zero for every call of TIOCOUTQ ioctl ( even though the serial port is sending something ).

Comment: What about [`QSerialPort::bytesToWrite()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#bytesToWrite)?

Comment: @Scheff it reports number of bytes written to linux buffer, like others

Comment: So, you want to access the OS state which is "under the hood" of `QSerialPort`?

Comment: @Scheff i think it should be

Comment: Found [How can I monitor serial port traffic?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/how-can-i-monitor-serial-port-traffic).

Comment: @Scheff i didn't understand, they are separate applications

Comment: There is ioctl called TIOCOUTQ which reports the number of bytes in output buffer but always return 0 ( while the serial port transmitting )

Comment: Yeah, separate applications. But they might be worth further investigation. Some (all?) of them might be open source and could provide inspiration... ;-) ...if no better idea at hand.

Comment: If you want to know the bytes sent for a progress bar you can use the [write()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) return value, that would be ok. But if you want to know exactly the number of bytes written to the serial port this is more tricky

Comment: One solution might be to split the data to be written into smaller chunks and send them as necessary.  Send the initial chunk after which the `QSerialPort::bytesWriten` slot can be used to update the progress and write the next chunk.  So you end up with an initializer/reactor scheme a'la `boost::asio` (if you see what I mean).  A bit finicky as it probably means maintaining more state on your part but it might give you the progress update granularity you're looking for.